# prompt using dialogs return undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

In my electron app, I am using [dialogs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogs) npm package to do prompts. I made a basic function for prompt replacement :

```js
function prompt(text){
    let returnval
    dialogs.prompt(text , val => {
        returnval = val
    })
    return returnval
}
```

And then I tested that function :

```js
let pro = prompt("Your name");
console.log(pro); //returns undefined
```

But in the console, it returns undefined even after the prompt is completed. Please help me in this. Answers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According description dialog.prompt is non blocking function so the function which you pass in it

```
val => { returnval = val}
```

works only when function prompt is already returned its value

So better return the promise

```
function prompt(text){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dialogs.prompt(text , val => {resolve(val)})
    })
}
```

then you can use it like this

```
prompt("Hi, there").then(answer => console.log(answer))
```

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd ok

Comment: Hello?? Are you there??

Comment: No, i'm not there, i am here and I edited an answer

Comment: wait here i'll try it real quick

Comment: what if i have to return value to user?? Waht should I do

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd, then you should use normal prompt instead of nonblocking dialog.prompt

Comment: Normal prompt is not supoorted in electron